# App crashing when chosing random numbers to select array index

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

**EDIT :** Solved. It was a silly silly mistake! Thanks for the fast response.
I have 6 arrays each having 150-200 elements . Now when I try to select the index numbers, the first two are selected jolly well but starting from the third index number, the app begins to crash. App had only one activity.

```
String A[]={};
String B[]={};
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void generate(View v) {
    tToast("Insult on your beep!");
    Gener();
}

public void Gener()
{

    int i1 = new Random().nextInt(A.length);
    String r1 = (A[i1]);

    int i2 = new Random().nextInt(B.length);
    String r2 = (A[i2]);

    int i3 = new Random().nextInt(C.length);
    String r3 = (A[i3]);

    int i4 = new Random().nextInt(D.length);
    String r4 = (A[i4]);

    int i5 = new Random().nextInt(E.length);
    String r5 = (A[i5]);

    int i6 = new Random().nextInt(F.length);
    String r6 = (A[i6]);

    String fin = r1 + r2 +r3 + r4 +r5 +r6;
    //Works OK up to r2 but from r3 error occurs
    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Gen);
    mTextView.setText(fin);
    tToast("Me works");
}
private void tToast(String s) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, s, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: I could not provide the arrays as they have sensitive information.

Comment: And LogCat says what?

Comment: Post the error you are getting

Comment: Use StringBuilder for concatinating the multiple strings that might be the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calculating random index for every array from A to F but trying to get the value of index from the A array. So this may cause ArrayIndex exception try to change your code like this

```
int i1 = new Random().nextInt(A.length);
String r1 = (A[i1]);

int i2 = new Random().nextInt(B.length);
String r2 = (B[i2]);

int i3 = new Random().nextInt(C.length);
String r3 = (C[i3]);

int i4 = new Random().nextInt(D.length);
String r4 = (D[i4]);

int i5 = new Random().nextInt(E.length);
String r5 = (E[i5]);

int i6 = new Random().nextInt(F.length);
String r6 = (F[i6]);

//Remaining code....
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the String's from the `A` array every time. I presume you want to select out of each of the different arrays for each String.

**Example**

Your code:
`String r5 = (A[i5])`

What I presume you want:

`String r5 = (E[i5])`